# Jquery quickSand Plugin

Tags: jquery, css, quicksand

Please see the working demo here :

[jQuery Quicksand demo](http://www.evoluted.net/thinktank/demos/simple-jquery-filtering-part2/)

Sources of the files could be downloaded from [here.](http://www.evoluted.net/thinktank/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/simple-jquery-filtering-part2.zip)

This sorts data in the following manner :

```
    A B C D

    E F G H

    I J K L
```

I am trying to make it sort and display like this :

```
A D G
B E H
C F I
```

I have altered the css to show it in 3 columns in place of 4 columns . But as per the sorting algo could you please suggest how it can be done ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking at a CSS centric approach for the results display. I would suggest having 3 `ul`'s each with `float:left` and fixed height and it's `li`'s being `display: block`. Since the height of each `li` is fixed, you can determine the total height of the `ul` easily to suit your requirements. That ways you can display the results exactly as you have described above.

Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes , I tried this solution but after reshuffling 3 ul's would become a single ul.hence breaking display,bcz quicksand does not regard the ul's.

Answer (score 0):

You could first sort the array, and obtain :

```
`sortedList = [A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,...]`
```

and from here compute a list which stores the items in the flow order for your display :

```
var colSortedList = [];
var gap = sortedList.length / colnumber;
var i, j;
for (i=0; i<colnumber; i++){
   for(j=0; j+i < sortedList.length; j+=gap){
       colSortedist.push( sortedList[j+i] );
   }
}
```

(this is an untested patch, one or two things need adjusting)

Now you can create your html items from colSortedList

[EDIT]

If I understand correctly, you have your initial `<ul id="source">` displayed, you need to build a new html node `<ul id="destination">`, and call `$('#source').quicksand( $('#destination') );`

If you want to "build a new html node" which sorts the items per column :

- use the above algorithm to have your items sorted in the correct order
- insert your `<li>` items following the order in `colSortedList`

Comment: Thanks for the help.Did you check quicksand.js , i need to alter the same in order to do this.